# Subviews size issue - UIView related sizing in xib

Tags: swift, uiview, xcode8, swift4.1.5

For a layout made of some views stacked in each other, which are all `subviews` of the `UIView` and I wanted to know how to automatically size the main `UIView`  which may be `multiline` once the app is live and updates come in.  `UIView` width is fixed.

Comment: Can you elaborate? We usually use collection views for dynamic data, but it totally depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the view (UIView) does size itself so i dont think you will face this issue.  Just try to not constrain the height and make sure you select appropriate stack view while doing this since you got multiple.  Hope this helps as i assume that you are not using collection view for this matter!